# How to fix "KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

My data is like

```
Keywords  ...       Task
Success  2021/12/27 18:15:31  ...  jasdljflasjflasjfljaslfjl...
```

I wanna drop the first row, I tried `data.drop([0],axis=0)` but it showed `KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'`
How could I fix this,.....

Comment: your solution remove indices `0`, what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: if need remove first row: `df.iloc[1:]`, if need remove first column `df.iloc[:, 1:]` should works

Comment: info()is like```#   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   Keywords     31324 non-null  object
 1   DateTime   31324 non-null  object
 2   Provider      31324 non-null  int64 
 3   EventID   31324 non-null  object
 4   Task    31324 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(1), object(4)``` and i tried ur advice it doesn't work (XoX)

Comment: So `df = df.iloc[1:]` not working?

Comment: Yes. = =, it shows exactly the same thing as ```print(data)```. I can't figure out why cause I know it shouldn't be like this. = =